# pickle load error "__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

Tags: python, pickle

My issue is that a custom class has been saved with pickle.dump, since these files were saved the custom class has been changed and now when I use pickle.load I am getting this error. Is it a problem with the saved file?

The error:

```
File "/cprprod/extern/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
return Unpickler(file).load()
File "/cprprod/extern/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
file "/cprprod/extern/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1070, in load_inst
self._instantiate(klass, self.marker())
File "/cprprod/extern/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1060, in _instantiate
value = klass(*args)
```

Is there anything I can do to load the file?

The code

```
file = open(filename,'rb')
obj = pickle.load(file)
```

will give me the error.

---

Here is some minimal code which can reproduce the error:

```
import pickle

class foo:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.a)

obj = foo(1)

with open('junk','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(obj,f)

class foo:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s'%(self.a,self.b)

    def __getinitargs__(self):
        return (self.a,self.b)

with open('junk','rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
    print str(obj)
```

Comment: what arguments does your current version of the class expect (within __init__) vs. the instantiated object can you give some examples?

Comment: Does your class implement `__getinitargs__()` or `__getnewargs__()` at all (at least when it was pickled)?

Comment: Something is fishy here.  `__init__` [shouldn't be called](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getinitargs__).  Is your class old-style or new-style?  Also, did you pickle a *class* or a *class instance*?  Does your class have a `__getinitargs__` method?

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- apparently I can't even get my comments in faster than you :p

Comment: @mgilson: And this was *with* me being a taxi when this was posted! :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I guess that's why I had enough time to write a small script to prove to myself that `__init__` wasn't actually called :-p -- And I take it you mean that you were *in* a taxi, no that you were a taxi (as that would be a bit strange...)

Comment: The class did not have __getinitargs__() when it was pickled. That was added as part of the change.

Comment: @mgilson: I blame SO conking out there for a sec for dropping the `in` in that sentence.

Comment: @wDroter: That is an important detail.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to load these old classes;/

Answer (score 3):

If you added `__getinitargs__()` then it is up to you to make sure your new class can handle the arguments passed to `__init__()`. Old data that doesn't have the `__getinitargs__` data will still lead to `__init__` to be called but with *no* arguments.

Make the arguments to `__init__` optional via keyword arguments:

```
def __init__(self, otherarg=None):
    if otherarg is None:
        # created from an old-revision pickle. Handle separately.
        # The pickle will be loaded *normally* and data will still be set normally
        return
    self.otherarg = otherarg
```

When loading the old-style pickle, the data for these classes will still be restored. You can use `__setstate__()` to transform the internal state as needed.

Alternatively, temporarily *remove* the `__getinitargs__` method from the class:

```
initargs = foo.__getinitargs__.__func__
del foo.__getinitargs__
obj = pickle.load(f)
foo.__getinitargs__ = initargs
```

and re-dump your pickles from the now-loaded objects with `__getinitargs__` reinstated.

I've tested both methods and in both cases the old data is loaded correctly and you can then dump your objects again to a new pickle file *with* `__getinitargs__` just fine.

Comment: My issue is that the previous version of the class has already been pickled and I am trying to load those files.

Comment: @wDroter: That's what we are attempting to help you with here.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to `a = klass.__getinitargs__;del klass.__getinitargs__;pickle.load();klass.__getinitargs__ = a`.  In other words, remove `__getinitargs__`, unpickle and then monkey-patch `__getinitargs__` back on... (although this is probably a much better way to go about doing it)

Comment: @mgilson: thing is, I was trying that out, but I cannot reproduce the OP problem here. This only happens if the pickled data actually has empty `__getinitargs__` values pickled, I suspect. In which case the data is useless anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Did you try the code I posted on OP's behalf to reproduce the problem?  It only works for *old* style classes, so make sure you're using python2.x

Comment: @mgilson: Yeah, testing with old-style classes here. Must've missed something; my initial test didn't include arguments for `__init__` (beyond `self`) at all.

Answer (score 2):

Given the contrived code that I posted on your behalf in the question, we can "fix" this error as:

```
with open('junk','rb') as f:
    try:
        obj = pickle.load(f)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        position = f.tell()
        a = foo.__getinitargs__
        del foo.__getinitargs__
        f.seek(position)
        obj = pickle.load(f)
        foo.__getinitargs__ = a

    print str(obj)
```

Now we see that the instance has been unpickled and no longer has attribute `b`.

Comment: Yup, was testing this out again against your example update, and it certainly works!

Comment: In fact, my initial method also works, and is a little less hacky in my view. Expanded to state that both methods do solve the OP problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yeah, Hence my comment on your answer "Although this [your answer] is probably a much better way to go about doing it"

Answer (score 1):

You might want to modify the custom class to optionally require a second parameter. This would keep back award compatibility with your pickled objects.

Comment: Thanks, however these have already been pickled as the previous version of the class.